# Correction of systematic multiplicative confounder effect

Tags: correlation, normalization

Dear community members,

I have a very simple question. I have thousands of independent large samples (>1000 data points each) from complex 1D distributions. To imagine the problem better, I describe it as thousands of blood pressure studies, performed in different hospitals with different cohorts of people, and the sphygmomanometers used in different hospitals introduce multiplicative constant (within one hospital) bias to measures. So the shape of these distributions is exactly the same, but the "scale" is different.

What would be the best way to normalize this data to one scale? The data is unpaired, so I can not just make a linear model to estimate the slope. I can not also use mean or median for comparisons - the distributions are complex and multi-modal, and mean/median become quite unstable so large sample size of each cohort does not actually help enough.

I can proceed with mixture of Normals fitting, but the distributions are not exactly normals, so it may lead to inaccurate normalization.

A simple example (in R) is (in reality the mixture contains up to 10 different components and some of them are quite extreme "outliers") - due to random sampling number of samples in small "extreme" components is different. Some small extreme components may be not even sampled in a particular set due to chance. Also the methods of robust statistics are inapplicable since the number of "outliers" is >50% since it is a mixture. Comparing many density quantiles should work fine on average, but I do not know how to do it.

```
bias = 1.5
distrib1 <- c(rnorm(990, mean=1), rnorm(10, mean=10)); 
distrib2 <- c(bias * rnorm(980, mean=1), bias * rnorm(20, mean=10)); 
plot(density(scale(distrib1),bw="SJ"));   
lines(density(scale(distrib2),bw="SJ"), col="red")
```

[image]

One may say that the difference is not so crucial here - in my opinion the small right cluster is very different after such normalization. Also variance of the "big" component is different after z-scoring.

Comment: If the distributions all have the same shape, why not divide each hospital's measures by the sample standard deviation from that hospital? This will result in each hospital having (1) distributions of the same shape, and (2) variance and standard deviations equal to exactly 1.

Comment: "the distributions are complex and multi-modal, and mean/median become quite unstable" Pretty sure that if you have 1000s of observations in each hospital your *sample means* are quite stable, and approximately normally distributed (unless these are serial data, such as several years of daily measures). Even Bernouli distributed data—about as non-normal as it gets—have sample means with unimodal bell-shaped symmetric distributions centered on $\mu$ at 1000s of observations.

Comment: @Alexis the problem is - each distribution is poorly described with standard deviation or mean. It is a mixture of distributions. Let's say we have 2 normal components in mixture - one has mean of 1, another a mean of 10 (sd=1). One set has 990 patients from the first component and 10 from another, another set - 980 patients from the first component and 20 from another (due to random sampling). SDs and means are very inaccurate...

Comment: If summary statistics themselves are the problem (and to be clear, I am not convinced that sample means are unstable if each 'hospital' has a distribution with an identical shape), then why not simply report each hospital's histogram (after, say, normalizing over the sample standard deviation)?

Comment: I can describe it with R code: distrib1 <- c(rnorm(990, mean=1), rnorm(10, mean=10));
distrib2 <- c(rnorm(980, mean=1), rnorm(20, mean=10));
plot(density(scale(distrib1)));
lines(density(scale(distrib2)), col="red")

Comment: Please add this extra information in comments as an edit to the post

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen already did! Should I provide a plot, or R code is fine?

Comment: You should provide a plot. Leaving your audience to try and do extra work to understand your question is not so good. :)